# Which key should I use to verify JWT's signed by Google?

Tags: google-oauth

Calling the `jwks_uri` (`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs`) from Google's OpenID Connect discovery URI returns a JSON object with not one but three different keys. How is one supposed to know which is to be used to verify a JWT signed by Google?

Comment: Is the `kid` specified in the header perhaps? (I still haven't gotten my hands on an actual Google JWT yet.)

Comment: Google prefers that you  call their tokeninfo endpoint to verify a JWT. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, Google's JWT does indeed include the `kid` in the header.